# Why do we use multiple convolutional layers, instead of a single layer

Tags: cnn, feature-extraction

My intuition is that, when we have the raw pixels from the image, suppose we want to extract an eye, why don't we just try to use an eye detector to extract the eye feature from the image, why do we need to start building from edges?

---

lets say an eye detector is a 3d filter consisting of a vertical line detector and the horizontal line detector, why dont we just use this and learn the values of our filters from training, why go through the problems of building deep networks?

Comment: The deeper are the layer, the more differentiation you can get. Let's imagine just one layer: how many different outputs can you have? Keep in mind that CNNs are used to detect shapes and deep networks are more suitable to detect any of them. But they require more calculation when the number of layers increase.

Comment: you get one feature map, showing if an eye was detected or not, is that not simpler?

Comment: If you just want to detect a specific shape having a specific dimension, maybe just one layer is enough, but I've never tried.

Comment: you can also have a nose detector and mouth detector in that single layer too, remember that a single layer can have multiple filters

Comment: my question is why make the network deep, and start with lines before shapes, when you can start with shapes first

Comment: Do you understand while fully-connected networks are deep, even though the [universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) says that a single layer is sufficient to figure out any decent function?

Comment: from what I understand, why it is deep is because it would be harder to extract more complex patterns from raw pixels, e.g trying to extract eyes from pixels, hence they are deep